# Change background when hovering image. if possible with css only (elmeentor)

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image, elementor

I have this grid here:

[what i want to have (image example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wff56.png)

When I hoverig one of them, all 4 parts should get hidden and the background image with the right color should appear.

How can I get this happen?

thx & best regards

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this you would have to use JavaScript, so what I am thinking is that you could create `<div>`'s for all the backgrounds and when you hover over one of them in JavaScript you could do the show hide to the ones you want.

And just for future note's you should include code and more details and check the web or try to solve it *before* you even ask on Stack Overflow.